# Child tags - Should [tag:Automated Testing] be on [tag:Selenium] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's say you're asking a question about Selenium. Should you also use the [automated-testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automated-testing) tag? I understand why it might be there, but it would seem that the question would have little to do with anything related to automated testing that isn't also directly related to Selenium.

Should it instead be that the [automated-testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automated-testing) tag be used only for questions that are only about automated testing? Or should it remain open to any question that falls under its umbrella?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I feel that it is a good umbrella tag.  Not really much different than adding C# to a WatiN question.  There are also times when a person may look through a specific tag, such as this and find a question or answer that they may not have realized that they had.  I know that I've done the same such thing a few times.